# DecoderException when trying to teleport player

Tags: java, plugins, netty, minecraft, bukkit

I create PvP Plugin for minecraft server, but when I press teleport to the world, I get an error:

```
Internal Exception: io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: readerIndex(47) + lenght(1) exceeds writerIndex(47): UnpooledHeapByteBuf(ridx: 47, widx: 47, cap: 47)
```

Already went through the code, there are 0 errors. This is my code:

```java
Location playerSpawn = new Location(map_world, spawn1x + moves * 200, (double)spawn1y, (double)spawn1z, (float) spawnYaw, (float) spawnPitch);
player.teleport(playerSpawn);

// then I send NPC to player
EntityPlayer npc = new EntityPlayer(server, world, profile, new PlayerInteractManager(world));
npc.setLocation(npcX + moves * 200, npcY, npcZ, 0.0f, 90.0f);
CraftLivingEntity cle = (CraftLivingEntity) npc.getBukkitEntity();
ItemStack itemstack = ItemUtils.getItem(Material.STICK, 1, Enchantment.KNOCKBACK);
cle.getEquipment().setItemInHand(itemstack);
EntityPlayer ep = ((CraftPlayer) p).getHandle();
PlayerConnection connection = ep.playerConnection;
connection.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo(PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo.EnumPlayerInfoAction.ADD_PLAYER, npc));
connection.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutNamedEntitySpawn(npc));
connection.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutEntityEquipment(npc.getBukkitEntity().getEntityId(), 0, CraftItemStack.asNMSCopy(itemstack)));
DataWatcher watcher = npc.getDataWatcher();
watcher.watch(10, 127);
PacketPlayOutEntityMetadata packet = new PacketPlayOutEntityMetadata(npc.getId(), watcher, false);
connection.sendPacket(packet4);
```

What can be taken with this error?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To be precise, we need to see some code in order to help you.

Comment: Welcome! The code is divided into several classes. So even the error does not write which class it is in...

Comment: @TweazyyNS just show a [mre] like only the code that teleport the player

Comment: I know, I just edit your question to show your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to comes because a value is too high to be writted as needed.

It seems to be `watcher.watch(10, 127)` :

The 127 is cast as int by Java. So, for bukkit, the DataWatch will send an int.

Your client receive an integer, so a value that can reach `2147483647`. Such as it was waiting for a byte (that can reach only `127`), it's kicked.

To fix it, such as "127" is an allowed value for byte, you just have to say to Java that you want to send int and not byte by using this :

```java
watcher.watch(10, (byte) 127);
```

Comment: compilation doesn't give out an error

Comment: Can you go to discord and see the code? I've been struggling with this error all day...